# Declare Variable & Data Retrieval

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, sql-server-2012-express

Recently, I asked a question regarding updating a column values by comparing against another table. The following worked perfectly, but due to the number of records, it takes a little bit of time.

```
 UPDATE Table1 
 SET [Count] = 
 (
     SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 
     WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID
     AND Table2.Val <= Table1.Val
 )
```

I currently have the above running as part of a stored procedure, and would like to somehow collapse it into the main Select query, which builds a staging table.

```
 Select a.col1, b.col2, b.col3 into staging_table (select      ...,)
```

After the above select query, the update query is run. While it works, it takes time. I was looking into Declaring variables, whose values would be set in the above select subquery, and then used in a subquery but I've reviewed some reference material, and I'm having a bit of trouble getting my head around it:

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-141.aspx

Your assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: you are not declaring a variable nor retrieving data. Which version of sql-server are you using ?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 Express with Advanced Services. I tried declaring a variable and setting one value to that variable to test, but it errored. So, when I researched further, I came across the link I posted in my first article.

Comment: Regarding "While it works, it takes time" -- is the real issue here the performance of the query? If so, maybe you need an index on Table 2 for the columns ID and Val.

Comment: Ah, indexxing. This brings me to my next question, in nonclustered indexes, how do you decide whether to add more than one column within a single index, versus, adding seperate indexes for each column?

Comment: This is too broad of a subject to cover in a comment on S.O. You should probably find a good online tutorial for these types of questions.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a `CTE`, I think it's good for when you have `aggregated functions` in `subqueries` for updateing :

```
 with cte as
    (
     select Table1 .id, count(*) cnt
     FROM  Table1 
     JOIN  Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.ID
                 AND Table2.Val <= Table1.Val
     group by Table1.id
    )   
 UPDATE Table1 
 SET [Count]  = cnt
 FROM  Table1  
 JOIN  cte on Table1.ID = cte.ID
```

Comment: I have no qualms with the update query, it works and I can live with it. I wanted to see if there was a better way to handle it, hopefully within the select subquery that dumps it all into the staging table. 

I was thinking that if I could declare variables, and store the specific values that I was getting in my select query, then I could use the variables to perform 'where equals' for those specific columns that are being updated at the end. Something like this ---- ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 
     WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID
     AND Table2.Val <= @val ) AS SomeColumnMatch

Comment: @user4656811 the updated statement suggested by Farheg should run faster then the one you are using right now.

Comment: An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, you are right,sorry I didn't notice that. thanks a lot for your comment. answer edited, you can react the voting.

Comment: would upvote if you had improved the script in the question. I don't see the improvement. I would prefer the other syntax

Comment: great, but I didn't mean upvote, I meant removing downvote if you did